# DHCP server not updating DNS server after assigning IP address?

Tags: domain-name-system, dhcp

I'm having mysterious issue that confused me for such a long time till now, I've got one DC which acted as DNS and DHCP as well.

However it is successfully giving out IP address to all IP enabled device and machine but when updating the DNS entry, only the Windows machine (workstations and server) gets their IP registered in the DNS server, therefore i cannot ping and access the other Linux machine apart from using IP address only.

restarting the DNS (plus RELOAD the entry) and DHCP services doesn't help at all and also entering the DHCP assigned IP address into the DNS server caused more problem since the address is assigned to different host already by DHCP but not gets updated in the DNS server (only to non-windows machine).

If anyone know how to diagnose and help me solve this problem that'd be very great helps.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm using Windows Server 2003 R2 SP2 64 bit AD integrated for both DNS and DHCP server.

Answer (score 2):

make sure your DHCP server is configured to dynamically update DNS on behalf of clients (DHCP Server properties, DNS tab)

Comment: yes i did this one already.

Comment: thanks, I set up username and password in DHCP server to authorize it to update DNS records.

Answer (score 2):

Check that your non-windows dhcp clients send out their hostname to the server.

Perform a packet capture (wireshark) on the client or the server (easier on the client, less packets) to verify this hypothesis.

If the client is not sending its hostname to the dhcp server, it has no way to update the dns zone.

Comment: Your DHCP clients need to be configured to register with DNS on update.  The default configuration for most Unix/Linux systems is to not update DNS.  I believe this is based on the assumption that they are clients, and do not need to be reachable by name, or servers already listed in static DNS with a static DHCP lease.